# Stack overflow in C++ with big array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Well, I am writing a program for the university, where I have to put a data dump into HDF format. The data dump looks like this:

```
"1444394028","1","5339","M","873"
"1444394028","1","7045","V","0.34902"
"1444394028","1","7042","M","2"
"1444394028","1","7077","V","0.0470588"
"1444394028","1","5415","M","40"
"1444394028","1","7077","V","0.462745"
"1444394028","1","7076","B","10001101"
"1444394028","1","7074","M","19"
"1444394028","1","7142","M","16"
"1444394028","1","7141","V","0.866667"
```

For the HDF5 API I need an array. So my method at the moment is, to write the data dump into an array like this:

```
int count = 0;
std::ifstream countInput("share/ObservationDump.txt");
std::string line;

if(!countInput) cout << "Datei nicht gefunden" << endl; 

while( std::getline( countInput, line ) ) {
    count++;
}

cout << count << endl;

struct_t writedata[count];

int i = 0;

std::ifstream dataInput("share/ObservationDump.txt");
std::string line2;

char delimeter(',');

std::string timestampTemp, millisecondsSinceStartTemp, deviceTemp, typeTemp, valueTemp;

while (std::getline(dataInput, timestampTemp, delimeter) ) 
{
    std::getline(dataInput, millisecondsSinceStartTemp, delimeter);
    std::getline(dataInput, deviceTemp, delimeter);
    std::getline(dataInput, typeTemp, delimeter);
    std::getline(dataInput, valueTemp);

    writedata[i].timestamp = atoi(timestampTemp.substr(1, timestampTemp.size()-2).c_str());
    writedata[i].millisecondsSinceStart = atoi(millisecondsSinceStartTemp.substr(1, millisecondsSinceStartTemp.size()-2).c_str());
    writedata[i].device = atoi(deviceTemp.substr(1, deviceTemp.size()-2).c_str());
    writedata[i].value = atof(valueTemp.substr(1, valueTemp.size()-2).c_str());
    writedata[i].type = *(typeTemp.substr(1, typeTemp.size()-2).c_str());

    i++; 
}
```

with `struct_t` defined as

```
struct struct_t
{
    int timestamp;
    int millisecondsSinceStart;
    int device; 
    char type; 
    double value; 
};
```

As some of you might see, with big data dumps (at about 60 thousand lines) the array `writedata` tends to generate a stack overflow (segmentation error). I need an array to pass it to my HDF adapter. How can I prevent the overflow? I was not able to find answers by extensive googling. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `struct_t writedata[count];` is a VLA and is not standard in C++.  If you want a run time sized array use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation, or at least the signature, of the function you're using that requires an array?

Comment: A `std::vector` is probably better than reading through the file twice, but another option would be explicit `new` and `delete` (or `malloc` and `free`, but those are more C than C++). All three options (`vector`, `new`/`delete`, and `malloc`/`free`) put the data on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: @dureuill Even for functions that require a C array, a `vector` works, because internally it stores its data contiguously.

Comment: @dureuill https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5T/h5ex_t_cmpd.c is the documentation of how I built my adapter.

Comment: @DanielH thanks for your help, will try `new` and `delete`

Comment: @Baesm [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is very easy to use, just replace your array with `std::vector<struct_t> writedata(count);`. It's easier and safer than using `new`/`delete`.

Comment: @Baesm The example code is C, not C++, and C does not have `vector`s available. Using `std::vector` is almost certainly the better solution. You also don’t need to read through the file twice; you just use `push_back` each time and the vector automatically grows.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux gives me `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<struct_t>' to 'struct_t*` at the moment. Will try to fix, thank you!
`

Comment: A `std::vector` is not itself an array or a pointer; it contains one. The `data()` member function gives you access to the underlying array (and the `size()` member function tells you how big it is).

Comment: @DanielH How is `std::string line2;` C code?  This is clearly C++ code.

Comment: @NathanOliver This question is about C++. The example code being followed, at https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5T/h5ex_t_cmpd.c, is C.

Comment: @DanielH Oh, that example code.  Carry on then. *whistles*

Comment: @DanielH thanks for pointing out to use `data()`! Works like a charm now, I am looking into `push_back` to save the first count loop. Therefore - case closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [example code](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5T/h5ex_t_cmpd.c) you are following is in C, while the code you are writing is it C++. In *most* cases, valid C code is valid C++ code, although not necessarily good style; this is one of the times where it is not, although since that isn’t your real problem I’ll leave the explanation of that at the end of my answer.

When you declare `struct_t writedata[count];`, you are creating an array on the stack. The stack is often artificially limited in size, and so creating a large array on the stack could lead to a problem where you run out of stack space. This is what you are seeing. The typical solution is to create large data structures in the heap (although the primary use of the heap is to make data that lasts past the `return` of the function that creates it).

The most C++-idiomatic way to access the heap is to not do it directly, but to use a helper container class. In this case what you want is an `std::vector`, which lets you push data onto the end and will automatically grow as you push on more data. Since it automatically grows, you don’t need to specify the size in advance; just declare it as a `std::vector<struct_t> writedata;` (read “`std::vector` of `struct_t`”). Again, since it doesn’t need to know the size in advance, you can also ignore the whole first loop.

The vector is initially empty; to put data into it, you usually want to use `writedata.push_back()` or `writedata.emplace_back()`. The first of these takes an existing `struct_t`; the second takes the parameters you’d use to create one. All of the elements are stored contiguously in memory, like in a C array, which you can access directly with `writedata.data()`.

At the end of the function, when the `vector` goes out of scope and is no longer accessible, its destructor will be called and automatically clean up the memory it used.

---

Another option, instead of using `std::vector`, is to manage the memory yourself. The C++ way of doing that is with `new` and `delete`. The easiest way to handle that is to still calculate `count`, as you do, but instead of creating the array on the stack by just declaring it as a `count`-sized array, you do `struct_t* writedata = new struct_t[count];`. This will create an array of `count` `struct_t`s in the heap, and set `writedata` as a pointer to the first element of this array. Then you can use it as you use the array in your program, but since it’s on the heap you won’t run out of stack space.

The downsides to this are that you need to know the size in advance, and you need to clean up the memory you used yourself. To do this, when you no longer need the data, you should run `delete[] writedata`. After that, `writedata` will still point to the same place in memory, but your program no longer owns that data, so you need to make sure to never use that value again; the standard way is to, immediately after deletion, set `writedata` to `nullptr`.

You can also use the C equivalents to `new` and `delete`, which are `malloc` and `free`. They are mostly equivalent in your case, but for more complicated examples you should keep in mind that these leave the memory uninitialized, while `new` and `delete` will run the constructors/destructors of what you create to make sure the objects are in a sane state at the beginning and don’t leave resources lying around at the end.

---

Now for why your original code isn’t actually valid C++ for any size of file: Your line `struct_t writedata[count];` tries to create an array of `count` `struct_t`s. Since `count` is a variable, this is called a *variable-length array* (VLA). Such things are legal in newer versions of C, but not in C++. This alone is just worth a warning as long as you only want to compile the code on the same system you’re currently using, since your compiler seems to support VLAs as an extension. However, if you want to compile your code on any other system (make it more portable), you shouldn’t use compiler extensions like this.

Comment: "if you want to compile your code on any other system", including your own system in the future. Bottom line, unless you know very well what you're doing, write valid C++.

Comment: GCC’s VLA support is relatively stable. There’s a difference between taking advantage of undefined, undocumented behavior and taking advantage of an explicitly-documented extension. I don’t know what compiler the OP is using, but I would bet that since it supports VLAs at all it probably explicitly documents this somewhere. It’s still less stable than a feature of the language, but it probably won’t just disappear on a whim or to support some optimization nobody’s invented yet.

Comment: Yes there is a difference, you're correct and I agree, gcc probably won't throw VLA through the window anytime soon. Using non standard features remains a trade-off, though, and usually not a good one, since it may not be portable to other compiler and due to other *standard* features of C++ (eg, use a vector w/ a custom allocator if you really can't pay for heap allocation while pushing elements. Usually, you *can* pay, though.). I stay by my point that you shouldn't use "dialect" features unless you know what you're doing. Another extension where the tradeoff is better is `#pragma once`.

Comment: @dureuill That’s why I listed it as a warning at the end of the answer even though VLAs being non-standard wasn’t the issue here. Often there are good reasons for using compiler extensions instead of any of the standard features, but you should at least be aware that they are extensions and even if you don’t plan to change build systems you should think twice before using them.

Comment: Just to revisit these comments, I recently fixed a segfault in some C++ code that was caused by VLAs in gcc-4.9 (from jessie-backports) when compiling with the flag -std=c++14. Replacing the VLAs by std::vector fixed the bug. The bug did not occur with clang or different -std values. So much for "gcc probably won't throw VLA through the window anytime soon".

Comment: @dureuill Do you know if it compiled in any version of gcc 5, 6, or 7? From your description, that could easily be a compiler bug, or undefined behavior in VLAs like you can get with any other language feature.

Comment: I didn't get to check with more recent compilers, I will certainly revisit this again when they become available to me. It could be undefined behavior in this particular use of VLAs, in which case it is bad news for me, as I certainly didn't remove it by replacing the VLAs w/ vectors... Honestly I hope for a compiler bug :D.

Comment: Note that there was work on VLAs on G++ 4.9.0: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/04/gcc-4.9.0, so a bug or a change of behavior is possible. Also, the code in question **was** using `sizeof(vla)`.

Comment: @dureuill Based on that it looks like using `-std=gnu++1y` should work, but I’m not sure because that had less than a paragraph about the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct_t writedata[count];
```

This array is allocated on the stack which is normally quite small, and when it gets to a value that's too big (which is semi-arbitrary) this will overflow the stack.
You'd be better off allocating on the heap by doing something like:

```
struct_t* writedata = (struct_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct_t) * count);
```

And then add a corresponding call to free once you're finished with the memory, e.g.

```
free(writedata);
writedata = nullptr;
```

It's best practice to check that `i < count` in your while loop, as if you write off the end of your array Bad Things may happen.

Comment: You should not be using malloc.  It does not call the constructor leaving all the elements in a uninitialized, undefined state.

Comment: There is no constructor in his struct

Comment: I would advocate `std::vector` over manual memory allocations. In any case this is c++, not c, you should be using `new` instead of `malloc`. Even then, prefer `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` over `new` for general cases.

Comment: @IainBrown Still a bad habit to get into.  Just use `new` and you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: This is a C answer to a C++ question. One, one could argue this is C++ because of the nullptr, but still...

Comment: I disagree entirely. You should use the simplest tool for the job, especially when learning a language. The OP doesn't seem to understand memory management and by showing him the simplest way of doing things he can hopefully understand the underlying principles before moving on to more complex methods.

Comment: How is malloc'ing with `sizeof` simpler than using higher-level structures like a vector? With a vector it will always work. With malloc it will cease to work for seemingly no reason when they will add constructors to their objects.

Comment: @IainBrown The word “simple” can mean almost opposite things to different people, but for any definition I’m not sure how `malloc` is simpler than `new`.

Comment: Because a vector will do memory management under the hood and can even relocate the entire array underneath you if you don't know what you're doing

Comment: No, it won't, if you use it like an array (not changing its size). If you start modifying the size of your vector, then 1° You really shouldn't use arrays anyway 2° you should learn the caveats of doing so.

Comment: @dureuill This isn't even a good C answer.  In C you should not be casting the return of `malloc`.

Comment: @IainBrown The fact that `std::vector` does things under the hood is precisely why it's a simpler solution than `malloc`. It hides the complexity behind an easy and safe interface. *Even if* `std::vector` was a bad solution, `malloc` would still be a bad answer. It's far trickier to use correctly than `new`. `new` doesn't requires a cast, doesn't need to be provided a size, and you don't have to ask yourself rather or not the type has a constructor. Saying `malloc` is "the simplest tool for the job" is a falsehood. Not to mention that owning raw pointers have no business here (std::unique_ptr)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Different people use the term “simple” in almost opposite ways. It can mean that the provided tools are simple and you get close to the implementation, or that the user experience is simple because all the hard stuff is done under the hood. It appears that Iain is using the first definition. There is something to be said for learning that style first so you understand what `std::vector` is doing when you learn about it, but I disagree that it’s the right approach here.